# could not parse the remainder: '[0].title' from 'i[0].title'

Tags: python, django

I am trying to render the data from the database one by one by it does not work.

index.html

```
{% for i in edus %}
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">{{i[0].title}}
                                            </a>
                            </h4>
                        </div>

                        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <p>{{i[0].descripiton}} </p>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to render specific index, you should change:

1. `{{i[0].title}}` into `{{ i.0.title }}`
2. `{{i[0].descripiton }}` into `{{ i.0.description }}`